# urlManagerFrontEnd unknown yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to direct from frontend to backend if user has already login so I did this in backend config

```
 'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'baseUrl' => '/backend/web',
    ],        
     'urlManagerFrontEnd' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'hostInfo' => 'http://localhost/frontend',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://localhost/backend',
    ],
```

and in controll I used this

```
 if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
       return $this->redirect(Url::to(Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl(['/site/index'])));
    }
```

but then I received exception
Getting unknown property: yii\web\Application::urlManagerFrontEnd
How can I fixed this

Answer (score 0):

You baseUrl path seems not complete  try adding the path to your app

```
 'baseUrl' => 'http://localhost/your_app_url/backend/web',
```